# AVX-512 extensions supported on new Skylake-X (Core i9, 79xxX/XE) CPUs

Tags: avx512

AVX-512 standard consists of many extensions, and only one (AVX-512F) is mandatory. What exactly is supported by new Skylake-X (Core i9, 79xxX/XE) CPUs? [Wikipedia page about AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) has details about Skylake Xeon CPUs (E5-26xx V5), but not about i9. Google also was not very helpful. I also tried to search for some dump of /proc/cpuinfo for this CPU, but without luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AVX512 has [its own wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512), which says Skylake X supports AVX-512 F, CD, BW, DQ, and VL.

The Aida64 dump found [here](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeX_InstLatX64.txt) agrees.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it also supported on Coffee Lake U processors?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe only AVX2, none of the 512bit extensions